# column_spec function in kableExtra in R doesn't work

Tags: r, pdf, latex, tex, kable

I want co change column width in pdf with kable ( , 'latex') but the fucntion doesn't work. Anybody know why? here is my code:

```
   table = knitr::kable(jeden, "latex" , row.names = F ,  align = "llrrrrrrrrrr" , escape = F, booktabs = F, caption = '1. Sprzedaz uslug i towarow razem') 
   kableExtra::column_spec(table, 1, width = "1cm", bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug but rather a relatively strange setting for `align` in `knitr::kable()`. In `xtable` you can put align in a string but for `kable`, you will have to provide a vector. In your case, if you put things like `align = c(rep("l", 2), rep("r"), 2)`, you should be fine.

Comment: wow, that work perfectly! awesome, many thanks!! I'vs lost a lot of time trying to do this...

Comment: @Hao Odd, still seems like a bug to me because `align = "llrr"` works for HTML output. It's only the PDF/LaTeX document that doesn't like a string.

Comment: Yeah, check out the documentation of kable https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.20/topics/kable, that "unless" made me laugh when I first read it. lol

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `align` breaks your `column_spec`, but only for LaTeX/PDF output.

Here are two minimal & reproducible examples.

**PDF output**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
x <- kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "latex", row.names = F, align = "llrr")
column_spec(x, 1:2, width = "4cm", bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)
```
````

[image]

If you remove `align` from the PDF RMarkdown document, `column_spec` works as expected.

**HTML output**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
x <- kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "html", row.names = F, align = "llrr")
column_spec(x, 1:2, width = "4cm", bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)
```
````

[image]

This seems like a bug to me, and I would suggest opening an issue on the [`kableExtra` GitHub site](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra). If you do, you should reference this post, and include a minimal & reproducible example (similar to what I did).

Comment: thanks, seems the same to me. I will open an issue, but i need quick solution for now. I removed aligning and customized column width but I need to align columns also, do you know  some other solution to do that?

Comment: @dorota Sorry I've got no quick solution other than editing the raw LaTeX file and manually changing/fixing column widths in the `tabular` environment.

Comment: hello again, another problem with kable function. maybe do you know if 'hline_after' parameter works properly? I have the code:     row_spec( c(grep( 'TOTAL', final[,3])),bold = T ,  hline_after=T  )     and bold works for every records and hline_after not for every. I have no idea why.